# During Dax Reboot, facing error : Endpoint is unreachable:. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-dax

Below is a stacktrace

client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established" Error: Endpoint is unreachable: 10.213.1.120:9111. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
at SocketTubePool.socketError (/Users/awagle/WebPlatform/amoeba/node_modules/amazon-dax-client/src/Tube.js:290:11)
at TLSSocket.tls.connect.on (/Users/awagle/WebPlatform/amoeba/node_modules/amazon-dax-client/src/Tube.js:277:103)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.